# How to replace a text with another text in a file present at HDFS

Tags: sed, hdfs

I have file.txt in UNIX file system. Its content is below:

```
{abc}]}
{pqr}]}
```

I want to convert this file.txt into:

```
[
{abc}]},
{pqr}]}
]
```

I am able to do this using below shell script:

```
sed -i 's/}]}/}]},/g' file.txt
sed -i '1i [' file.txt
sed -i '$ s/}]},/}]}]/g' file.txt
```

My question is what if this file were present on HDFS at /test location.

If I use : `sed -i 's/}]}/}]},/g' /test/file.txt`

It would look at unix partition /test and say file does not exist.

If I use : `sed -i 's/}]}/}]},/g' | hadoop fs -cat /test/file.txt`

It says -----  sed: no input files and then prints content of file.txt as per cat command.

If I use `hadoop fs -cat /test/file.txt | sed -i 's/}]}/}]},/g'`

It says ----  sed: no input files
cat: Unable to write to output stream

So, how shall I replace strings from my file at HDFS with some other string?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With `sed` and `hdfs` commands:

```
hdfs dfs -cat /test/file.txt | sed 's/$/,/g; $s/,$/\n]/; 1i [' | hadoop fs -put -f - /test/file.txt
```

where,

`hdfs dfs -cat /test/file.txt` is for getting the HDFS file content

`s/$/,/g;` is for adding a comma at the end of each line

`$s/,$/\n]/;` is for removing comma at the line and adding a newline with a bracket

`1i [` is for adding a bracket at the first line

`hadoop fs -put -f - /test/file.txt` is for overwriting the original file in HDFS